# Regular expression for the Mask="h:mm tt" MaskType="DateTime"

Tags: regex, silverlight

There are so many resources that it is confusing and many are commented with users saying this does not work etc.

can any one please give me a perfect regex for Mask="h:mm tt" MaskType="DateTime" to be used in my silverlight project

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match something like this: `Mask="h:mm tt" MaskType="DateTime"`

This is a regex for it:

```
Mask="(1[0-2]|[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]) (am|pm)" MaskType="(.+?)"
```

Your match will contain:

1. hours
2. minutes
3. AM/PM
4. value of MaskType

You should specify in the question what you want to match for.